# Is it possible to set a TTL on CosmosDB container in EF Core's OnModelCreating?

Tags: entity-framework-core, azure-cosmosdb

In EF Core, OnModelCreating scaffolds the entire database, but I don't see a way via the model builder to define a TTL; It seems like I would have to delete the container that gets created by EF Core.

Does anybody know of a better solution?

Comment: I am looking for a solution as part of an internal escalation to assist you. Regards, Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is possible now. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-6.0/whatsnew#configure-time-to-live

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Family>(
    entityTypeBuilder =>
    {
        entityTypeBuilder.HasDefaultTimeToLive(100);
        entityTypeBuilder.HasAnalyticalStoreTimeToLive(200);
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Eoleary. Although there is full support for [Entity Framework Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/) and Cosmos DB including the [EF Core Azure Cosmos DB Provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/cosmos/) with almost full support for the [CosmosClientOptions Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.cosmosclientoptions?view=azure-dotnet). The TTL component will not be available until v. 6.0 dotnet\efcore nugget package at the earliest. You can track this through the following dotnet\efcore Git Issue: [Cosmos: Configure TTL per entity/entity type/collection](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/17307)

[Version 3.1.9 is GA](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos/3.1.9) and version 5 release candidate is [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Cosmos/5.0.0-rc.2.20475.6). Additional information can be found on the [dotnet/efcore project repository](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore#repository).